# AsyncTask accessing Database - Where to initialize, close?

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask

When accessing a database within an `AsyncTask`, should the database connection be a member of the parent `Activity` or opened/closed within each `AsyncTask`?

If the connection is a member of the activity, I'm concerned that when switching between my application's activities there is the possibility that the database connection could be closed before the AsyncTask utilizing it has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not something I've ever really thought about but instinctively I'd make the AsyncTask as self-contained as possible, i.e., have it handle its own db operations internally. The same applies to any threaded code.

EDIT: Here's a link to a good article discussing multiple access to SQLite in Android...[Android SQLite Locking](http://kagii.squarespace.com/journal/2010/9/10/android-sqlite-locking.html)

Comment: Does the SQLite database take issue with having multiple open connections? For example, if two AsyncTasks are spawned simultaneously.

Comment: @Karl H: Databases are designed to have multiple connections although you do have to take care if more than one write operation is occuring which may involve the same 'subset' of data. I admit I haven't done much with the Android implementation of SQLite but I've been using the Windows version of SQLite for a while now without problems.

Comment: @Karl H: I've edited my answer to include a link to a discussion on multiple access to SQLite on Android - hope it's of help.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The article mentions several good observations.

Comment: Linked article is down. [Google cache here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SS-SETrwkz0J:kagii.squarespace.com/journal/2010/9/10/android-sqlite-locking.html+kagii.squarespace.com/journal/2010/9/10/android-sqlite-locking.html&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=ubuntu&source=www.google.ca)